# how to display images from rest api to fronted but it display only in image using multer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

it displays only the image logo fronted, not the whole image which I uploaded in my backend in string format please resolve my error what is my problem in my code...

[image: section.js (fronted)]

[image: post route in backend and (upper part)]

[image: post route in backend and (below part)]

[image: Backend main file server.js]

when I see it in the browser then it renders me as below

[image: on browser]

please help me to run out of it...

Comment: Please upload codes instead of images. Otherwise it is hard to copy and search the codes to debug.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your Posts include not url of your image. They include filename. You need to write your full path to the image.
Your server is listen in http://localhost:5000
So you need to write:

```
<img src={`http://localhost:5000/${post.image}`} />
```